# Laravel form validation result

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with the messages of Form Validation Laravel.

This is my FormRequest class

[image]

and here's the result I get during validation

[image]

But I want a result of this type

[image]

Is it possible ?

Comment: why you need this? you just want to print all the errors ?

Comment: I need this kind of message in order to exploit it with android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$validator->errors()` returns a [`MessageBag`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html), The `all()` function will give you an array with all error messages.

```
$validator->errors()->all();
```

Comment: Thank you that's what I wanted

Comment: Consider marking this as the answer. this way other users might find this solution as well.